# Directly accessing objects in an array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I have the results of a  database query stored in a variable $lists

print_r gives me the following output:

```
DB Object
(
     [_pdo:DB:private] => PDO Object
          (
          )

     [_query:DB:private] => PDOStatement Object
          (
                [queryString] => SELECT * FROM lists
          )

     [_error:DB:private] => 
     [_results:DB:private] => Array
          (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                     (
                          [id] => 10
                          [list_name] => Farmer
                     )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                     (
                          [id] => 11
                          [list_name] => Gardener
                     )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                     (
                          [id] => 12
                          [list_name] => Plumber
                     )

          )

     [_count:DB:private] => 3
)
```

By using a for loop I can access the  list_names as follows:

```
foreach ($lists->results() as $person) {
    echo $person->list_name;
}
```

This gives me:
Farmer
Gardener
Plumber

What I want to do is directly access the list_name but I simply can't understand how to.

Comment: I don't understand? You seem to be getting the desired result?

Comment: I din't want to use a loop, I want to directly access the data.

Comment: if you use arrays, you have to use loops or know the exact index of the one you want. If you don't want to use loops, you need to use objects, although there I would still suggest using loops...

Comment: I will at all time know the index of the value I require.

Comment: Then just go `people[index]-> list_name`

Comment: That give the error: Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type DB as array

Comment: Then in the PHP you need to make use of the  Reflection Object Class (`http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php`)